# Protect static content in WordPress application, hosted on Bluehost

Tags: php, wordpress, membership, bluehost

[Sory for my bad English]

Hi!

I'm angular developer, has no knowledge in WordPress.

I developed a small app, and was asked by the customer to upload it to his website.

His site is a WordPress site, hosted on Bluehost.
Because angular application is a client code, I copied (with cPanel file manager) the files to a subfolder within the site folder, and i can serve them successfully.

But now, I have to protect my app.
That is: while the entire site is open to the world, my app, which is stored in a subfolder, should be for internal use by the organization, and open only to registered users.

Ther is any way to do it with WordPress/Bluehost infrastructure, without write new user management applicatoin?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: your app is a pure client app (html/js) without server side code(nodejs/php) ?

Comment: Yes. For the purpose of the discussion, my app is `index.html` file, contains "Hello World" text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could auth user using WordPress's accounts system, it's the easiest way. Just rename your `index.html` to `index.php` and preappend the code blew to the header of `index.php`

```php
<?php
require_once __DIR__ . '/../wp-load.php';
// check if a wordpress user has logged in
if (!is_user_logged_in()) {
    $app_url = (isset($_SERVER['HTTPS']) && $_SERVER['HTTPS'] === 'on' ? "https" : "http") . "://$_SERVER[HTTP_HOST]$_SERVER[REQUEST_URI]";
    // redirect to wordpress login page
    wp_redirect(wp_login_url($app_url), 302);
    exit;
}
?>
<!-- your code begin -->
<html>
my app content
</html>
```